# pylint/flake8 linter check equivalent to "name 'x' can be undefined" and "local variable 'x' might be referenced before assignment" in PyCharm

Tags: python, pylint, pep8, flake8

When viewing the following Python code in PyCharm, PyCharm will report a helpful warning `Name 'x' may be undefined`:

```
condition = False

if condition:
    x = "foo"

print(x)
```

And with this code, PyCharm will report `Local variable 'x' might be referenced before assignment`:

```
def func():
    condition = False
    if condition:
        x = "foo"
    print(x)
```

Performing linting checks with pylint (2.6.0) and flake8 (3.8.3) won't report any errors on this code.

However detecting this problem in CI can prevent serious bugs hitting production.

How can I detect this problem without PyCharm (or PyCharm inspect.sh), are there any plugins available for flake8/pylint I'm missing?

Comment: did you find any way to check this? thanks

Comment: You can run PyCharm inspect from commandline: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-code-inspector.html#options Seems it can only be run for a full pycharm project though.

Comment: There is an open issue to add this functionality to pylint:
https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/85